# SQL Server Simplifying WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Could anybody help me with this sample statement:

```
declare @test int = 5
declare @temp table (id int, name varchar(20))

insert into @temp
values (1,'John'), (1,'Jenny')

if (@test = 5)
begin
    select * 
    from @temp a
    where a.id = 1
      and a.name ='Jenny'
end
else
begin
    select * 
    from @temp a
    where a.id = 1
end
```

I am pretty sure it goes simpler with just one SELECT and IF or CASE in WHERE.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please describe what you want the logic to do.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select a.*
from @temp a
where a.id = 1 and
      (a.name = 'Jenny' or @test <> 5);
```

Note:  if you anticipate that `@test` could be `NULL`, then the logic needs to take that into account as well.